# Customized distro to live-USB

Tags: live-usb, lubuntu, distributions

Need to run lubuntu in several workstations, but can't replace the existing distro. Also need to have Octave running, but it's not included in lubuntu. I would need to install Octave and the scripts that are to be run with it in a single computer with the same architecture, and then generate a live-USB containing all this (lubuntu + Octave +  scripts), and been able to copy it to a number of sticks, so every student can run it in a different computer (even at home).

I've heard of Yocto Project, can it solve this problem?

Comment: Uh? Octave is in Ubuntu. Just install the package.

Comment: lubunto 15 does not, I've just tried to install, but it needs an internet connection to fetch deb files.

Comment: Of course you need to obtain the package somehow. The **installation disk** of Lubuntu doesn't include all the packages in the distribution (it wouldn't fit on a DVD or USB stick). You can make your own installation disk including a customized set of packages if you want.

Comment: But, how? How can this live-USB be generated?